# Boost serialization tutorial program, error after running

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libraries, boost-serialization

I just installed boost-serialization with default options and get this result

```
ashot@ashot-desktop:~/boost_1_53_0$ sudo ./b2 install

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 20271 targets...
```

I downloaded boost serialization tutorial file http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp and compiled it.

After running i am getting this error

```
ashot@ashot-desktop:~/c++$ g++ demo.cpp -lboost_serialization
ashot@ashot-desktop:~/c++$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.53.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You might have to run ldconfig on your node, so it creates the proper symbolic links in to the boost libraries.  This is generally necessary any time you update your system shared library paths.